# How to call table AVG() in php

Tags: php, sql

```
foreach($result as $row){

array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=> $row->AUTOINDEX, "y"=> $row->AVG(`VALUE_`)));

}
```

It's error when I used AVG(`VALUE_`)

I tried to use SQL to create chart in php

```
foreach($result as $row){

array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=> $row->AUTOINDEX, "y"=> $row->AVG(`VALUE_`)));

}
```

when AVG(`VALUE_`) is error HTTP ERROR 500
But normal table name in database as VAULE_ is not error.

How can I fix it!
I errored cus I used AVG()?

Comment: Error 500 is broad. What is the error message?

Comment: It shows only Error 500.

Comment: Check the logs, then

Comment: I'm not sure `VALUE_` should be wrapped into backticks ` . Give a try to quotes, simples `'` or doubles `"`

Comment: I think It errored cus I used AVG() and call it in php like normal column????

Comment: Are you talking about the SQL aggregate function `AVG()` here? Well you have to call that in an SQL statement, not in PHP …

Comment: I adapt from this https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/chart-data-from-database/.

Comment: Yes, I created sql use AVG() and need ti use them for my chart

Comment: try $row->{'AVG(`VALUE_`)'}

Comment: Just give the column an Alias of your own choosing, then you don’t have to deal with the automatically created, more complex column identifier you normally get when using aggregate functions.

Comment: I tried {'AVG(VALUE_)'}  and it's not error but the chart is not shown. TT

Comment: @misorude Yes, I have no idea. can I ask you?

Comment: The comment has escaped my backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an object property. So you either assign an alias to the temp column.

```
"SELECT *, AVG(`VALUE_`) as average FROM table_name"
```

Then you can access it by $row->average in your foreach loop.

OR use curly braces so the context inside will be treated as a string. Otherwise, you are making an attempt to call a method from $row.

```
$row->{'AVG(`VALUE_`)'}
```

Comment: php doesn't know AVG(`VALUE_`) is a column name from your query. php takes is as a method(function) $row->doSomething($arguments).